# Prove that If $f$ is polynomial function of even degree $n$ with always $f\geq0$ then $f+f'+f''+\cdots+f^{(n)}\geq 0$.

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I can't solve this problem:

Suppose $f$ is polynomial function of even degree $n$ with always $f\geq0$.

Prove that
$f+f'+f''+\cdots+f^{(n)}\geq 0$.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Let $g=f+f'+\cdots+f^{(n)}$ and let $h(x)=e^{-x}g(x)$. Note that $f^{(n+1)}=0$, so
$$h'(x)=e^{-x}(g'(x)-g(x))=-e^{-x}f(x)\le 0,$$ 
i.e. $h$ is decrearing on $\mathbb R$.
Since $g$ is a polynomial, $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}h(x)=0$. It follows that $h\ge 0$, and hence $g\ge 0$.

Comment: Why lim h(x) goes to zero?

Comment: @user75086: As $x\to +\infty$, the exponential function $e^x$ tends to $\infty$ much faster than any polynomial function.

Answer (score 52):

Alternatively, by a standard Maximum Value Theorem argument, the even-degree polynomial $g=f+f'+\dots+f^{(n)}$ has a global minimum at some point $a$. Then $g(a)=f(a)+g'(a)\ge 0$, so $g\ge g(a)\ge 0$.

Comment: It's nice and more natural than my argument. +1.

Comment: why $g(a)=f(a)+g'(a)\ge 0$?

Comment: @user75086: Because $g'(a)=0$ and $f(a)\ge 0$.