# Let $f:R\to R$ a polynomial from degree $n\in N$, such that $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in R$. Explain why n is an even number.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, polynomials

> Let $f:R\to R$ a polynomial from degree $n\in N$, such that $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in R$.
>
> 1.) Explain why n is even.
>
> 2.) Let $g= f+f'+f''+...+f^{n}$ (where $f^{k}$ is the kth derivative). Prove that g has an absolute minimum on R.
>
> 3.) Prove that $g(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in R$

1.) Given the function is $\ge 0$ means that the leading coefficient is positive. Using limits, when x approaches $ \pm \infty $ for even polynomials, the limit is $\infty$.

Since f is a polynomial, f is continuous on all R.

When x approaches $\pm \infty$ for odd polynomials the limit is $\pm \infty$ and from the intermediate value theorem, f(x) must take on every value in-between $\pm \infty$, therefore exists c such that $f(c) \lt 0$ which is a contradiction to what we were given.

2.) Again, g is a polynomial of an even degree. How to solve this is beyond me.

3.) Again, not sure where to begin.

Id appreciate any help.

Comment: For $2$, $g(x)$ has degree $n$ with positive lead coefficient clearly (same leading term as $f(x)$) Hence even degree...so it is bounded below.  Not clear to me why it has to be $≥0$ though...

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414541/prove-that-if-f-is-polynomial-function-of-even-degree-n-with-always-f-geq0?rq=1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88260/sum-of-derivatives-of-a-polynomial

Answer (score 3):

Note that $g'(x)=g(x)-f(x)\le g(x)$. Hence $g(x)\ge 0$ whenever $g'(x)=0$.